# PL/Python With PostgreSQL - Error DLL import

Tags: javascript, python, linux, windows, postgresql

We are suffering from importing third-party modules into PL/PYTHON with PostgreSQL. I hit the PATH paths, but when running PostgreSQL doesn't find the DLLs

Windows 7 64 bits - PostgreSQL 9.5 - Python 3.7.9

```
ERROR:  ImportError: DLL load failed: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "teste", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
  PL/Python function "teste", line 42, in <module>
  PL/Python function "teste", line 10, in <module>
  PL/Python function "teste", line 2, in <module>
  PL/Python function "teste", line 233, in create_module
  PL/Python function "teste", line 208, in load_module

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION teste ()
RETURNS TEXT
AS $$
    import requests

    a = requests.get('https://api.github.com')
    
    return a
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpython3u';
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is English only site. For Portuguese see https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: edited in your language, sorry

Comment: You will have to install a matching Python.

Comment: change from 3.7 to 3.3 for example?